# Qual o gênero da palavra webinar?

Tags: gênero, neologismos

Durante essa época de pandemia do novo coronavírus ouvi, entre outras tantas, a palavra [webinar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webinar); os seminários baseados em *web*. Várias pessoas referem-se a tais seminários como *o webinar* em alusão *ao seminário*, outros tantos falam *a webinar*, possivelmente aludindo à palavra *web*.
Pensando nisso, qual seria a forma correta para o gênero dessa palavra?

Answer (score 6):

Masculino: **o** webinar.

A palavra já está dicionarizada, sendo encontrada como substantivo masculino no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/webinar) e na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/webinar), além do próprio [verbete](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webinar) da Wikipedia já citado na pergunta.

Uma variação que também se encontra, e de gênero talvez mais claro, é o [webinário](https://dicionario.priberam.org/webin%c3%a1rio).

Comment: Que maravilha! Já temos a versão em nossa língua. Vou passar a usá-la.